# Chart.js chartjs-node-canvas this._chartJs is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js

I am trying to create Chart using Chart.js on backend I have followed [chartjs-node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node-canvas/v/3.2.0)
but getting `TypeError: this._chartJs is not a constructor`
My **Chart.js** version is `4.2.0` and **chartjs-node-canvas** version is `3.2.0`

I think the versions are conflicting but not quite sure so please help me
Thanks in advance :)

Here's the code

```
const { ChartJSNodeCanvas } = require('chartjs-node-canvas');
const width = 400;
const height = 400;
const chartCallback = (ChartJS) => {};
const chartJSNodeCanvas = new ChartJSNodeCanvas({ width, height, chartCallback });

(async () => {
  const configuration = {
  type: 'bar',
   data: {
     labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
      datasets: [
       {
         label: '# of Votes',
         data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
         backgroundColor: [
           'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
           'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  ]
},
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          callback: (value) => '$' + value
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
};
 const image = await chartJSNodeCanvas.renderToBuffer(configuration);
 const dataUrl = await chartJSNodeCanvas.renderToDataURL(configuration);
 const stream = chartJSNodeCanvas.renderToStream(configuration);
 })();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `chartjs-node-canvas` README says [here](https://github.com/SeanSobey/ChartjsNodeCanvas#chartsjs-version), you need chart.js version 3.x.x